# Difference between aov() and ezANOVA when using a subset of DataFrame in repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I ran into something I do not understand when conducting a repeated measures ANOVA.

Short description: I'm using a dataset included in the `ez` package. When I conduct a repeated measures ANOVA on the full dataset, the results of ezANOVA and `aov()` are equivalent. However, once I take only a subset (in this case: only reaction times for trials without error) the results with `ezANOVA` and `aov()` differ.

The longer story: 
The dataset contains a subject column (`subnum`), two within subject factors (`cue`, `flank`) and the dependent variable (`rt`). 
The dataset can be loaded via

```
library('ez')
data(ANT)
df = ANT
df$cue <- as.factor(df$cue)
df$flank <- as.factor(df$flank)
df$subnum <- as.factor(df$subnum)

subnum group block trial cue  flank  location   direction   rt  error
1   Treatment   1   1   None    Neutral     up  left    398.6773    0
1   Treatment   1   2   Center  Neutral     up  left    389.1822    0
1   Treatment   1   3   Double  Neutral     up  left    333.2186    0
1   Treatment   1   4   Spatial Neutral     up  left    419.7640    0
1   Treatment   1   5   None    Congruent   up  left    446.4754    0
1   Treatment   1   6   Center  Congruent   up  left    338.9766    0
1   Treatment   1   7   Double  Congruent   up  left    399.3715    0
```

Now when I perform a repeated measures ANOVA on the full dataset, and use both `ezANOVA` and `aov()`,the results are the same.

```
ezANOVA(
  data=df,
  dv=rt,
  wid=subnum,
  within = .(cue, flank),
)

$ANOVA
     Effect DFn DFd F p p<.05 ges
    2 cue  3  57  540.862407  7.988172e-42 *  0.87793881
    3 flank  2  38  1066.037656  4.196305e-34 *  0.91110583
    4 cue:flank  6  114  4.357093  5.356773e-04 *  0.09416982
$`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
        Effect  W   p   p<.05
    2   cue     0.8431739   0.69690404  
    3   flank   0.7999302   0.13411237  
    4   cue:flank   0.1378186   0.03419366  *
$`Sphericity Corrections`
        Effect  GGe p[GG]   p[GG]<.05   HFe p[HF]   p[HF]<.05
    2   cue     0.9016877   6.126025e-38    *   1.0657965   7.988172e-42    *
    3   flank   0.8332849   8.590878e-29    *   0.9037852   4.869100e-31    *
    4   cue:flank   0.5956263   4.652864e-03    *   0.7506166   2.015937e-03    *
```

For `aov()`:

```
mod123 <- aov(rt ~ (cue*flank) + Error(subnum/(cue*flank)), data = df)
summary(mod123)


Error: subnum
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 19  85489    4499               

Error: subnum:cue
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
cue        3 5523668 1841223   540.9 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 57  194041    3404                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:flank
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
flank      2 7871119 3935559    1066 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 38  140287    3692                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:cue:flank
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
cue:flank   6  79837   13306   4.357 0.000536 ***
Residuals 114 348147    3054                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
            Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 5520 14422221    2613
```

So until now, everything works fine.
But if I select only those observations where error equals zero, the results between both approaches differ:

```
ezANOVA(
  data=df[df$error==0,],
  dv=rt,
  wid=subnum,
  within = .(cue, flank),
)

$ANOVA
     Effect DFn DFd          F            p p<.05        ges
2       cue   3  57 477.564650 2.435084e-40     * 0.86387868
3     flank   2  38 958.640865 3.040261e-33     * 0.90297213
4 cue:flank   6 114   4.047785 1.026734e-03     * 0.08633287

$`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
     Effect         W          p p<.05
2       cue 0.8670854 0.77271988      
3     flank 0.9088146 0.42293876      
4 cue:flank 0.1506008 0.04917243     *

$`Sphericity Corrections`
     Effect       GGe        p[GG] p[GG]<.05      HFe        p[HF] p[HF]<.05
2       cue 0.9165014 3.647676e-37         * 1.086943 2.435084e-40         *
3     flank 0.9164345 1.182224e-30         * 1.009411 3.040261e-33         *
4 cue:flank 0.6261487 6.059761e-03         * 0.799682 2.641207e-03         *

mod123 <- aov(rt ~ (cue*flank) + Error(subnum/(cue*flank)), data = df[df$error==0,])
summary(mod123)


Error: subnum
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
cue        3  22044    7348   2.037  0.187  
flank      2  31873   15936   4.418  0.051 .
cue:flank  6  12677    2113   0.586  0.735  
Residuals  8  28858    3607                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:cue
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
cue        3 4818840 1606280 445.910 <2e-16 ***
flank      2    3512    1756   0.487  0.617    
cue:flank  6   24626    4104   1.139  0.354    
Residuals 49  176510    3602                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:flank
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
flank      2 7195298 3597649 936.928 <2e-16 ***
cue:flank  6   17408    2901   0.756   0.61    
Residuals 32  122875    3840                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:cue:flank
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
cue:flank   6  73202   12200   4.096 0.000928 ***
Residuals 114 339584    2979                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
            Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 4951 12871045    2600
```

What am I missing here?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that selecting observations with `error == 0` gives you an *unbalanced design*.  `ezANOVA` will take cell means for you and pretend that you have a balanced design, but `aov` will not.

Let's balance the design ourselves and see that the outputs match:

```
> data <- aggregate(rt ~ subnum + cue + flank, ANT[ANT$error == 0, ], mean)
> ezANOVA(data, dv=rt, wid=subnum, within=.(cue, flank))
$ANOVA
     Effect DFn DFd          F            p p<.05        ges
2       cue   3  57 477.564650 2.435084e-40     * 0.86387868
3     flank   2  38 958.640865 3.040261e-33     * 0.90297213
4 cue:flank   6 114   4.047785 1.026734e-03     * 0.08633287

$`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
     Effect         W          p p<.05
2       cue 0.8670854 0.77271988      
3     flank 0.9088146 0.42293876      
4 cue:flank 0.1506008 0.04917243     *

$`Sphericity Corrections`
     Effect       GGe        p[GG] p[GG]<.05      HFe        p[HF] p[HF]<.05
2       cue 0.9165014 3.647676e-37         * 1.086943 2.435084e-40         *
3     flank 0.9164345 1.182224e-30         * 1.009411 3.040261e-33         *
4 cue:flank 0.6261487 6.059761e-03         * 0.799682 2.641207e-03         *
> summary(aov(rt ~ cue * flank + Error(subnum / (cue * flank)), data))

Error: subnum
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 19   4247   223.5               

Error: subnum:cue
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
cue        3 225486   75162   477.6 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 57   8971     157                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:flank
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
flank      2 330651  165326   958.6 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 38   6553     172                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subnum:cue:flank
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
cue:flank   6   3357   559.5   4.048 0.00103 **
Residuals 114  15759   138.2                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - of course! That unties the knots in my head.